My cookies are not expiring. JavaScript problem
I am trying to learn cookies in js but the name=value pairs aren't disappearing from the console when I set a well past due expiration date. I think it has something to do with the error code with the CSP. Does anybody know how to fix it?
the js code:
document.cookie = "firstName=Bob; expires=Sat, 1 2025 23:59:59 EST; path=/";
document.cookie = "lastName=Roberts; expires=Sat, 1 2000 23:59:59 EST; path=/";
console.log(document.cookie);

console line 1: firstName=Bob; lastName=Roberts
1 issue: Content Security Policy of your site blocks the use of 'eval' in JavaScript`
I tried changing time zones, and dates, and updating VSC.

This question is similar to: How to delete a cookie?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Think your date strings are just incorrect, this deletes those cookies:
document.cookie = "firstName=; expires=Sat, 1 Jan 2000 23:59:59 EST; path=/";
document.cookie = "lastName=; expires=Sat, 1 Jan 2000 23:59:59 EST; path=/";

